# How can I put the inputs value in the table cells in the first row when I clicked the button?

Tags: html, jquery

I have 3 inputs (name,email,address) and 1 button ,and I have table consists of (id,name,email,address). How can I put the value of the input in cells in the first row?

When I added new values it added up in the second row and so on, and the id increase automatically in every row when I click the button?

```
<form>
  <input class="Name" type="Name" name="" placeholder="Name">
  <input class="Email" type="Email" name="" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="Address" type="Address" name="" placeholder="Address">
  <button>click</button>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="t1">
        <td class="id"></td>
        <td class="nam"></td>
        <td class="em"></td>
        <td class="add"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id"></td>
        <td class="nam"></td>
        <td class="em"></td>
        <td class="add"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id"></td>
        <td class="nam"></td>
        <td class="em"></td>
        <td class="add"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="id"></td>
        <td class="nam"></td>
        <td class="em"></td>
        <td class="add"></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.nam').text($('.Name').val());

    });

    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.em').text($('.Email').val());
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.add').text($('.Address').val());
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting value when button click, generate markup to append with the table. Using `length` you can easily increase `id` like below. It's done by a single button click,

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  var html = "";
  var id = $('table').find('tr').length;
  var name = $('.Name').val();
  var email = $('.Email').val();
  var add = $('.Address').val();
  if (name != '' & email != '' & add != '') {
    validateYourEmail(email);
    if (!validateYourEmail(email)) {
      alert("Please post valid email")
    } else {
      $('#tblinfo').show();
      html += '<tr  class="t1">';
      html += '<td class="id">' + id + '</td>';
      html += '<td class="nam">' + name + '</td>';
      html += '<td class="em">' + email + '</td>';
      html += '<td class="em">' + add + '</td>';
      html += '</tr>';
      $('table').find('tbody').append(html);
    }
  }
  else
  {
  alert('* ...... All information are required.');
  }
});

function validateYourEmail(email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test(email);
}
```

```css
#tblinfo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="Name" type="Name" name="" placeholder="Name">
<input class="Email" type="Email" name="" placeholder="Email">
<input class="Address" type="Address" name="" placeholder="Address">
<button>click</button>
<table border="1" id="tblinfo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Suggestion:

1. Don't create an empty table just append `<tr>` when the button click.
2. Hide your table when it's empty using `CSS`.
3. only show your table when the button clicks to add information.
4. Use Regex to validate your email  (You can also use some plugin  to validate the email and empty field like [validatejs](https://validatejs.org/))

Comment: Thank you for posting answer can you make fiddle or something?

Comment: Run snippet to see a demo. Thanks.